# Should var statements be placed at the top of functions?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jslint

If you follow jslint.com guidelines, it makes you put them at the top of the function and consolidate mutliple statements like this.

```
function(){
    var foo,
        moo,
        hoo;
```

However, while learning underscore.js and and backbone.js I see that this convention is not followed, they are used as needed.  For example.  For example in _.each()

```
  for (var key in obj) {
```

Is one way more readable?  Is one way faster?

I know javascript does not have block scope.

Comment: There is no best way, and there is no speed difference.

Comment: Variables are hoisted, so they are always at the top of the scope they are in anyway, so you don't really have to put them at the top, and often times assigning values to variables has to be done where the values are available, so there is no best practice for this, other than doing what works.

Comment: ...you changed the question to ask *"Is one way more readable?"* Well... you tell me. Whether or not one is more readable than the other is obviously subjective.

Comment: there are no objective measures of readability ( sarcasm )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a matter of programming style, as the script works the same either way.

As variables are hoisted, i.e. declared before the code in the function starts, it makes sense to declare them at the beginning of the code, as that more closely resembles what's happening.

The performance is the same regardless of where you declare the variables.

Comment: Unlikely since the code is parsed before it is executed, so hoisting adds no cost. But why don't you time it if you are unconvinced?

Comment: @pure_code: An IIFE will naturally take up a little more memory, as the function is an object that needs to be created.

Comment: future proofing - Harmony will support block scoping.  So less code to re-factor if you ignore jslint.  Also, when working w/ bigger chunks of code, not consolidating var statements helps with encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

"Which way is fastest" is easy to answer: Whichever way allows you to write and maintain your code quickly. This is about source code quality, not execution-- the interpreter can do it either way.

Older programming languages, including early versions of C, only supported variable declarations at the start of a function. Doing it this way gives you an immediate overview, in one place, of the variables used in a function: The code has predictable structure. The ability to declare variables anywhere was added later, because many folks found it to be convenient and a good idea: It allows you to declare variables near the place where they are used, so the declaration and the use can be inspected and managed together: The code has more modular structure.

Since this is about human factors, which one is "better" is a completely open question. Style guidelines are a different matter: Style conventions are meant to be a reasonable way of doing things, not necessarily the only good way. But following a convention gives you the benefit of consistency, and readers of the code know what to expect. If you're writing code in a context for which there is a conventional style, follow it. What you gain in clarity and consistency is worth much more than what you *might* be giving up by not following some other style.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way and there is no speed difference between the two approaches. Both are exactly equivalent since declarations are "hoisted" and available in the entire function. (Although they have no value until assigned one.)

That said, I have noticed that people tend to use `var` inside a `for` loop for the looping variable, even if they put the rest of their declarations at the top.  The reason for this is probably because they want to signal to the code reader that this var isn't used in the rest of the function and is a throw-away loop var (treat as if it's only relevant to this block.)

These uses of `var` will probably be replaced by `let` as Javascript 1.7 becomes widely adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions are usually made to help you read code, making maintenance cheaper/faster, this specific convention may help though i don't feel it is necessary.

However, the example you gave is the declaration of an increment variable meant to be used only for the loop, that variable should not be used outside of the loop (except in rare occasions), and therefore it makes perfect sense to declare it, use it, and once the loop is done forget it (or clean it up, though that is rarely needed).